# Short circuit in DIY brushed DC motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, short-circuit

Recently I've been trying to make a simple brushed DC motor out of copper wire, neodymium magnets, AA battery and some parts that I want to print on 3D printer. I searched on internet how other people made this motor and I found these videos:

https://youtu.be/GVUDGFKfOa4 
https://youtu.be/BD0EV3hmtOc

What strikes me is that they basically create a short circuit. Isn't it bad for battery? Or is there any chance that it'll explode?

I checked it myself and connected copper coil to AA battery. There are some sparks at first but no heat is being produced on battery. So is it actually ok to do this?

I tried adding 100ohm resistor but resulting field was too weak to influence magnets. However when I added 10ohm resistor it just burned down.

Is there any way to make this DC motor without any health hazards?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AA batteries in  are very safe. If you say they don’t get hot, I would not worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The motion of the rotor generates a voltage that opposes the supply voltage. That limits the current when the motor is turning. Just before the motor starts to turn, the current is limited only by the resistance of the winding wire and the internal resistance of the battery. Therefore you must prevent the motor from being connected to the battery but not turning. In that case, the current could damage the motor or battery.

Comment: So you are saying that I only have to worry about situation in which rotor stands still and circuit is closed, right? Is it then ok to open circuit then manually rotate rotor and then while rotor is still rotating close circuit?

Comment: Yes - and that is generally true of just about any motor : stalling it causes enormous current consumption and wasted energy as heat. In your case (especially with a tiny battery) I wouldn't worry about switching on the power as long as you flick the motor into life within a second or two.

Comment: @Whistleroosh It's also okay if the motor starts turning by itself, because it's only stopped for a moment which isn't enough time for things to overheat. If the motor *stays* stopped, then it's a problem.